# Integration testing / Unit testing - How to decide

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, moq

I have controller API methods for which I have to write test case methods. As of now, I've been writing integration test methods for the project. I'm not sure how to frame unit test case methods for API methods like below:

`EmployeeController.cs`

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult PostCancelEmployee(EmployeeRequest req)
{
    string id = req.EmployeeId;
    EmployeeDetails mgr = new EmployeeDetails(id);
    response = mgr.CancelEmployeeDetails(req);
}
```

If I write integration test cases, then the sample input / request parameters keep changing according to the database, and that causes the test cases to fail. Can someone help me write unit test cases using the Moq framework for these type of API methods?

Answer (score 0):

[The Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api#testing-actions-that-return-ihttpactionresult) has some good examples of using Moq to unit test API controller methods. Here is a basic example of what your refactored controller might look like.

**EmployeeController:**

```cs
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    IEmployeeRepository _repository;

    public EmployeeController(IEmployeeRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        Employee employee = _repository.GetById(id);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(employee);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(Employee employee)
    {
        _repository.Add(employee);
        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = employee.Id }, employee);
    }
    
    [HttpDelete]
    public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        _repository.Delete(id);
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult Put(Employee employee)
    {
        // Do some work (not shown).
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, employee);
    }
}
```

The biggest change here is decoupling the *usage* of your class that interacts with the database from its *creation*. In your example, you are instantiating a new `EmployeeDetails` in your API method. It is preferred to inject any dependencies into your controller as an interface so that it can be easily mocked in your tests.

Here's an example unit test that verifies the `EmployeeController`'s `Get` method return type and data:

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void GetReturnsEmployeeWithSameId()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockRepository = new Mock<IEmployeeRepository>();
    mockRepository.Setup(x => x.GetById(42))
        .Returns(new Employee { Id = 42 });

    var controller = new EmployeeController(mockRepository.Object);

    // Act
    IHttpActionResult actionResult = controller.Get(42);
    var contentResult = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Employee>;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult);
    Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult.Content);
    Assert.AreEqual(42, contentResult.Content.Id);
}
```

Other test examples that cover the remaining API methods are included in the linked documentation.

And as for *what* to test, generally it's recommended to validate:

- The action returns the correct type of response.
- Invalid parameters return the correct error response.
- The action calls the correct method on the repository or service layer.
- If the response includes a domain model, verify the model type.